# How to fix running toilet if pushing down on the fill valve is the only way to stop it?

Tags: toilet

My toilet runs without stopping.  As I say in the title, the only way to hear it stop is if I push down on the fill valve directly from the top.  This is not something where it fills then stops and then after a while fills again, rather it is consistently running to a small degree.

I was guessing it might be the shank washer on the fill valve.  Is this a possibility, or what things could go wrong if the above temporary remedy is the only way to make the toilet stay quiet?

Comment: Is the tank overflowing into the fill tube? Could you [edit] to add a picture of your particular fill valve?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a bad "o" ring on the plunger or a bad seat seal on the valve base. You should  be able to get replacement parts at your home store but I've found replacing the entire fill valve to be a quicker and more complete fix to the problem.

Comment: Agreed, JACK.  Depending upon the toilet, the entire assembly is pretty cheap (less than $20, I think) and then everything is new again. In most cases, easy to replace.  My youngest son had a running toilet that needed new guts.  He's not handy at all, but I made him do it as I supervised and he did a fine job. +

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach, circa 2020, is to replace the entire fill valve.

Given a WIDE variety of toilet fill valves, and no idea what kind you have, it's hard to speculate whether the one you have is economically repairable or not, much less what particular part it might or might not be.

If the shutoff valve outside the toilet operates as it should, that is one way to "make the toilet be quiet" and manage the problem until you can do a proper repair - turn it on when you are using the toilet, turn it off when the toilet is full after using the toilet.

That would also reveal if there is a small leak (tank to bowl) causing the constant running, since the water level should not drop while the shutoff valve is closed (without flushing.) if it does, the problem is not, or not entirely, your fill valve.